# Right click not working on web2py site

Tags: jquery, python, html, css, web2py

Somehow I managed to break right click on the entirety of my site. The site is powered by web2py, but I have done heavy modifications to `layout.html` which is extended by other views.

I don't even know where to start as far as posting code, so I'm really just looking for ideas as to what could have broken right click. everything else appears to be working just fine.

Right clicking on other sites works fine so its not my mouse... Also, when right clicking on a `<a class"btn">` it appears to "depress" on right click, however the onclick is not triggered so it knows its not a normal click.

No exceptions are being thrown in the JS console.

I know this is a poor question, but any ideas? Has this ever happened to anyone before?

Comment: A code sample? Link to your site? The only real way to break right-click is to register a right-click handler that suppresses the default action

Comment: If nothing else, you can start by posting all of the JavaScript that is applied to the entire website (or whatever pages right-click does not work on). Use something like PasteBin.

Comment: site is not live to link and there is a whole lot of code. No right click handlers have been assigned. 

I know this is a really hard question to answer but I can literally strip every thing out of the view to just `<html></html>` and still no menu pops up on right click.

Comment: Clear your browser cache

Comment: it was a web2py bug, not abrowser issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. After literally stripping my view to:

```
<html>
</html>
```

and still no right click, I figured it was something in web2py. Navigating to the appadmin interface and still having no right click confirmed that. Restarting the web2py server fixed the problem. Weird bug. But i guess downvotes are cool too.